# Couldn't define user password in fstab

Tags: samba, solaris, mount, fstab

I am trying to add the below entry to /etc/vfstab on Solaris 11.2 to mount a windows shared folder on reboot time:

```
//192.168.1.45/share    -   /mnt/winshare  smbfs    -   yes fileperms=0777,dirperms=777
```

the shared is working, mount folder exists, the only issue that I don't know how and where to set the domainname, username, password, and the other issue that my password having @ character on it so if I used some thing like user:p@ss@192.168.1.45 it won't work.

Kindly advice.

Answer (score 2):

As said at [fstab and cifs mounting, possible to store authentication information outside of fstab?](https://serverfault.com/questions/222074/fstab-and-cifs-mounting-possible-to-store-authentication-information-outside-of) , you can use a credentials file:

> `credentials=filename`: Specifies a file that contains a username and/or password. The format of the file is:
>
> ```
> username=value
> password=value
> ```
>
> This is preferred over having passwords in plaintext in a shared file, such as /etc/fstab. Be sure to protect any credentials file properly.

Example from /etc/fstab:

```
//192.168.1.45/share   /mnt/winshare   cifs   credentials=/root/.creda,domain=yourworkgroup
```

Be sure to limit file permissions to 600 on credentials file, and assure owner is root:root:

```
chown root:root /root/.creda
chmod 600 /root/.creda
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I did that before with 0600, and I got unknown option "credintial", but I will try it again now

Comment: Well, in fact, 0600 is still better than 0700. Corrected the answer. Also note you've got a typo: credintial vs credentials.

Comment: Also forgot to ask: how about windows domain name, shall I add it to the credential file?

Comment: Thanks for correcting I am trying now, will get back to you

Comment: To fix the domain name, use `domain` option:
`//192.168.1.45/share   /mnt/winshare   cifs   credentials=/root/.creda,domain=yourworkgroup`. Updated the answer, too.

Comment: There are plenty of options at the manual. Execute `man mount.cifs` to see them all.

Comment: Still asking me for the password, I have noticed you are using only 4 fields while I am using 7 fields

#device  device  mount  FS fsck mount mount
#to mount to fsck  point  type pass at boot options

Also I am using filetype smbfs, when i use cifs I got: FSType cifs is not installed on this system.

My system is SunOracle Solaris 11.2

Comment: @emi  Given you mention `/etc/fstab`, is your answer intended for a Linux server?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: yes, it is. Didn't noticed masker was talking about /etc/**v**fstab.

Comment: @masker: mount.cifs is the solution Debian and Ubuntu are using to implement Samba, instead of old mount.smb . I don' t know Solaris very much. Maybe you can find `mount.cifs` on your package manager?